# Google Spreadsheets Script to send e-mails & keep count of total e-mails sent

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm still learning the ropes here & was hoping somebody could kindly suggest the best way of going about this (I have searched for a solution but to no success!):

I have very simple spreadsheet:

Column A: e-mail addresses; Column B: messages to send. (Column A is generated using a formula which grabs a few e-mail addresses from a longer list of addresses in Sheet2.)

Sheet2 contains a 'master' list of all the e-mail addresses.- Column A: Name; Column B: e-mail addressess

I am using the code below as a starting point. It send e-mails to the addresses in Sheet1, and marks the cells in Column C with "EMAIL_SENT" whenever the e-mail is sent (or rather when the script is done processing that row).

I'd like to keep count of the total number of e-mails sent to each person in column C of Sheet2, however I don't know what the best way to approach this would be, or if I'm honest, where to start!

```
function sendEmails() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
  var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange()
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2];     // Third column

    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates

      var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";

      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
}
}
}
```

So as mentioned, I'd like to keep count for each person in Sheet2, because it contains everyones e-mail addresses (whereas Sheet1 only has a handful of these and this list will change daily).

Can anyone please shed some light on this? Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Find the row in Sheet2 where that email is located.

```
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
var numRows = sheet2.getDataRange().getNumRows();
var emailList = sheet2.getRange(1,2,numRows,1).getValues();
var emailRow = -1;
for (var j=0; j<numRows; j++) {        
  if (emailList[j][0]==WHATEVER_EMAIL_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR) {
    emailRow = j;
    break;
  }
}
if (emailRow==-1) { /*ERROR! Couldn't find email.*/ }
```

Step 2: Get the old count of emails.

```
var oldValue = sheet2.getRange(emailRow+1,3).getValue();
```

Step 3: Write in the new value + 1.

```
sheet2.getRange(emailRow+1,3).setValue(oldValue+1);
```

Note: emailRow is zero-based, while getRange() is one-based.

Comment: Hello Phil, Thank you for your solution. Unfortunately I can't get the code to loop through all of the emails in sheet1. It was working before I added your code, so I guess I'm putting your code in the wrong place? Please could you tell my why this isn't working: I replaced 'WHATEVER_EMAIL_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR' with 'emailAddress' and I added Step1 code at the bottom of my script, directy under "SpreadsheetApp.flush();". I pasted step 2 & 3 code under step 1 code directly under " { /*ERROR! Couldn't find email.*/ }". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apologies. That's because I unintentionally reused the variable `i`. Change all times that I used `i` in my Step 1. That should fix it. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, Phil. The script now works perfectly. My apologies for not spotting that either!

Comment: I just noticed another 'i' that needs replacing, which I can't edit since it's less than 6 characters. It's within: "for (var j=0; i<numRows; j++) {". Also, should it not be j<=numRows, rather than  j<numRows?

Comment: Fixed it. =) All better now.

Comment: So I take it that it should be j<numRows, not j<=numRows?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that question. It should be j<numRows. I mentioned that emailRow is zero-based. This means that the first element of the emailList array is index 0. Thus the second element is index 1. And the last element is at index numRows-1. So we want the last iteration of the loop to be when j=numRows-1.

Comment: Thank you for clarifiying that. And thanks again for your help! Kind regards